# Unable to Upload Images on Local Windows Install

Tags: uploads, errors

I am having the Famous `has failed to upload due to an error
Unable to create directory` error that soo many people run into.

Any search on Google of StackExchange will result is the common, change your file/folder permissions answer.

Well I am running WordPress vs 3.5.1 on Windows 7.  Permissions aren't as simple as setting `chmod 777` on Windows.  I have check and even tried resetting the File permissions on Windows which from what I can tell is basically setting a user as the owner.

Has anyone who has had this problem on Windows actually ever fixed it?  All my searches never resulted in an answer for a Non- Linux or Mac

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add details what web server are you using and how is it run.

Comment: @Rarst I am running Apache on XAMPP.  S I have mthis particular site mapped to `http://domain.dev` instead of `localhost/domain` and I just noticed my other WP installs that are accessed through Localhost URL instead of a Virtualhost, those one allow Upload without a problem

Comment: @Rarst ahhh I spoke too soon, I just installed the same site into my localhost and it still doesnt allow uploads.  What is strange to me is I have hundreds of wordpress sites running on my computer for development and only a couple of them behave with this upload error.   Worth Mentioning both the newer Uploader and the older one don't work

Answer (score 3):

After trying many things with permissions, I found my problem.

I uses a plugin called Duplicator to move WordPress installs around from server to server, it handles changing URLS's and Paths.

So in `settings => Media => Store uploads in this folder` it was setting the Full Filepath to my Uploads folder.  I changed it to be relative `wp-content/uploads` instead of full like this `E:/Server/htdocs/projects/sitename/www/wp-content/uploads` and the problem went away!

Comment: It saved our day!